# In Microsoft SQL Server, how can I disable "X rows affected" at the end of my output?

Tags: database, sql, ms-sql

I'm querying a database in Microsoft SQL Server and writing the output to a csv file. 
When importing the outputdata into another program i get an error because the last line of my output file contains "X rows affected".
Is there a way to make sure SQL Server does not write this last line to my output file? Right now I first have to open the file in a texteditor and delete the last line, but since my file contains 20M rows loading the file takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your procedure block or before the slice of DML code you are working with, add the setting:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

This will prevent the summary line.

Note that this will not affect return values for SProcs; those refer to the status (0 => OK) of the resultant invocation, not the count of records affected.

Comment: I just added this at the top of my query:
"SET NOCOUNT ON"
In a test query with a few rows this seemed to work